# Is there any way to prevent a DELETE/UPDATE query to use the primary key greater than/less than comparison?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, safe-mode

In MySQL/MariaDB there's the SQL_SAFE_MDOE that prevents you to run a query without using a primary key in the where clause.

But even with that flag on I could run a query such as

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id > 0;
```

And that would pretty much have the same effect as

```
DELETE FROM table
```

So, is there any way to be more restrict? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe so!

Comment: Nowadays, I believe this option is, for instance, to shield script developers from writing a delete query and omitting the 'where' part (or a buggy 'where' variable that is actually empty), and IDE like JetBrains warn you about that mistake. Adding 'where id > 0' to the query looks more like an intent than a bug...

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a stored procedure that deletes in a manner you specify, and let the user call the procedure.

Then revoke DELETE privilege on that table from the user, so they can't delete directly. They would have to call the procedure.

The SQL_SAFE_MODE can always be circumvented, either by changing the session variable, or by using a WHERE clause as you show, or by using a LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) for the purpose of the `sql_safe_updates`.

> For beginners, a useful startup option is --safe-updates (or
> --i-am-a-dummy, which has the same effect). Safe-updates mode is helpful for cases when you might have issued an UPDATE or DELETE
> statement but forgotten the WHERE clause indicating which rows to
> modify.

If you want to restrict the deletes based on your logic, you can create a delete trigger.